# Program implementation with using specific CPU instructions

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, instructions, microprocessors

I want to realize following steps:

```
unsigned c = 5
c=c*5
```

I must do this by using this architecture and using 3 instructions at MOST:

[CPU Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRhzT.png)

Sample instructions for the cpu are like:

[instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0joRu.png)

Extra info about the problem:

> Suppose that the program is stored in instruction memory starting at address 0, and that each address in the memory holds a single 16-bit instruction. Assume that each CPU register has a starting value of 0xFF and is 8 bits wide. Assume that variable "a" is mapped to the R0 register in the program below and that R1 is used as a temporary register for calculations.

I tried many ways but in all ways i used more than 3 instructions.

extra: [datapath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc3lq.png)

Comment: If you tried many ways, why not show your best one or two?  FYI, the CPU diagram doesn't shed much light on the complete instruction set, and a sampling of instructions doesn't help much either; for example, we don't know if there is a multiply instruction.  However, any reasonable compiler would do the multiplication at compile time and generate runtime code for the value 25 (were variable `c` not eliminated as unused).

Comment: dear Erik,Firstly thank you for your comment. best solution i found is that using 1 NOT( to make the register 11111111 to 00000000), 4 ADI ( to make the c value 25). I think this doesnt look meaningful and i did not want to mention it. Sorry for that. My professor claims that by looking these pictures I have to understand the instruction set. (i added one more pic at the bottom of my question).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some analysis of what we can see.

---

Let's analyze the `ADI` instruction.  If, say, a 5 bit unsigned immediate is allowed we could simply add 26 to the pre-existing -1 to get the 25 in one instruction.

So, our question is what are the possible immediate values allowed?  To answer this, we can look at the definition in RTL of `ADI`, which is `R[RD] = R[RS] + zf I(2:0)`.  This says that there is an immediate field encoded in the low three bits of the instruction.  The RTL also suggests that the 3-bit immediate field is zero filled or zero extended, suggesting that field encoded values 0 to 7 mean operand values of the same.  (If it hinted toward sign extension of the 3-bit immediate, that would imply a range of -4 to 3.)

---

In one diagram there's a shifter near the ALU.  It takes an `H` input of 2 bits, which I take as an encoding for the shift amount.  (This is almost certainly encoded in the low 2 bits of the instruction for shifting, similar to how the immediate is encoded in the `ADI`' instruction.)

(Given such a small field, 2 bits, it is silly to waste an encoding with a meaning of shift by 0 bits.)

For the 2-bit field, we have the possible encodings and their meaning that we're guessing at.

| Instruction Encoded Value | Possible meaning (A) | Possible meaning (B) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | shift left by 1 | shift left by 1 |
| 01 | shift left by 2 | shift left by 2 |
| 10 | shift left by 3 | shift right by 1 |
| 11 | shift left by 4 | shift right by 2 |

Either way, with an educated guess, it looks like it can shift left by either 1 or 2 bits.  (In fact shifting left by 1 bit is potentially a silly encoding choice since that can be accomplished with addition to self.)

---

So, armed with that analysis of the potential instructions, can you try some more alternatives?

Comment: I guessed the shifter's 2-bit control might select left/right logical, right arithmetic, or rotate in one direction, all one bit shifts.  But yeah, multi-bit shifts are also possible.  I guess the instruction-set listing must be partial since it doesn't include anything that would use the shifter, unless address-generation does that.

Comment: If we already had an input in one register, we could multiply by 5 in three `add` instructions, two to double it twice to get `c*4`, then adding the original `c`, since it's a 3-operand ISA with a non-destructive separate destination.  (Big waste of bits vs. more registers for most real-world programs, but convenient for toy programs with only a couple live variables.)